# Iterate := assignment across columns in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I'm able to use the following to generate/replace a numeric column (var) with each cell's quartile rank (1-4) for the column:

```
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, var:=ntile(var, 4)]
```

I want to iterate this conversion over each of the columns in the data table. When I try the following, every cell in the table becomes the number, 1. Any guidance on why I'm not getting the expected output? I'm sure there's also a simpler approach, so alternatives are welcome too. Thanks!

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df))
{
  df[, colnames(df)[i]:=ntile(df[i], 4)]
}
```

Comment: Welcome, due to the lack of data it is hard to write a full answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to create a minimal reproducible example. But you probably can replace the for loop with the dplyr mutate_all statement, which would result in something like df %>% mutate_all(ntile(. , 4))

Comment: `df[, names(df) := lapply(.SD, ntile, 4)]`.

Comment: Thanks, both! The lapply method worked perfectly! @IceCreamToucan